# Disable beforeunload when submitting a form with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

How can I, without using any third-party libraries such as jQuery, disable the `onbeforeunload` event when submitting a form?

I have:

HTML:

```html
<form id="confirm_form">
    <input id="confirm_btn" type="submit" value="Confirm Action">
</form>
```

JS:

```js
function onLeave() {
    return "Are you sure you wish to leave without performing the action?";
}
window.onbeforeunload = onLeave;
```

This question is not a duplicate of [How to disable beforeunload action when user is submitting a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787995/how-to-disable-beforeunload-action-when-user-is-submitting-a-form) or [window.onbeforeunload - Only show warning when not submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766658/window-onbeforeunload-only-show-warning-when-not-submitting-form?noredirect=1&lq=1) because those are specifically dealing with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("confirm_form").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

Or, if you want to do this for every form in the page:

```js
function remove_onbeforeunload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
let forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for(let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms.item(i).addEventListener("submit", remove_onbeforeunload);
}
```